# Alternatives for System.Xml.Linq to match Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, .net-framework-version

I have used  `System.Xml.Linq;` to match Xpath from xml document. `XElement` and `SaveOptions` both get from `System.Xml.Linq;`.

```
           XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46");

            XElement docRfsid = XElement.Parse(content);
            //if (docRfsid.XPathSelectElement("//ns:RFSID", nsmgr).Value != null)
            if (Regex.Match(docRfsid.ToString(), "RFSID", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
            {
                projData.RfsId = docRfsid.XPathSelectElement("//ns:RFSID", nsmgr).Value.ToString();
            }

            XElement doc_Financial = XElement.Parse(content);
            string resultFinancial = doc_Financial.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Financial", nsmgr).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

I just want to remove `System.Xml.Linq;` dll since I have to use .net framework 2.0 only.
Is there any other alternatives that I can use to `System.Xml.Linq;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), specifically the [SelectNodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hcebdtae.aspx) method on it, the [DocumentElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement.aspx) property or any [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) instance. This method accepts an XPath and returns a list of XmlElements that match (whether they be nodes (XmlNode) or attributes (XmlAttribute)). This is based off the old COM XmlDocument object and is available as far back as version 1.1 of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

System.Xml

Something like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46");
XmlNode financialNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNode("ns:Financial",nsmgr);
strring resultFinancial = null;
if (financialNode != null)
{
  resultFinancial = financialNode.InnerText;
}
```

Sort of thing.